# How can I get localized quotation marks with pandoc?

Tags: pdf, localization, latex, locale, pandoc

I would like to get quotation marks like these „...” but when I process my markdown text wih Pandoc, it gives me “...”. It probably boils down to the question how to make Pandoc use locale settings? Here is my command line:

```
pandoc -o out.pdf  -f markdown -t latex in.md
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to specify the language for the whole document, so that it not only affects the quotes, but also ligatures, unbreakable spaces, and other locale specifics.

In order to do that, you may specify the `lang` option. From [pandoc's manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#language-variables):

> **lang**: identifies the main language of the document, using a code according to BCP 47 (e.g. en or en-GB). For some output formats,
>   pandoc will convert it to an appropriate format stored in the
>   additional variables babel-lang, polyglossia-lang (LaTeX) and
>   context-lang (ConTeXt).

Moreover, the same manual states that:

> if your LaTeX template or any included header file call for the csquotes package, pandoc will detect this automatically and use \enquote{...} for quoted text.

In my opinion, the best way to ensure quotes localization is thus to add:

```
---
lang: fr-FR
header-includes:
- \usepackage{csquotes}
---
```

Or even better, to edit the pandoc default template

```
pandoc -D latex > ~/.pandoc/templates/default.latex
```

and permanently add `\usepackage{csquotes}` to it.

Comment: According to https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf, you need to add also `csquotes: true` to the frontmatter.

Comment: @rriemann you need the variable to be "set to a true value" which happens, iirc, as soon as the string "csquotes" appears in the latex template

Comment: @rriemann @scoa Actually it's sufficient to _only_ include `csquotes: true` in the yaml block, which saves you the somewhat ugly `header-includes` and is just nicer (and more descriptive) in general.

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc currently (Nov. 2015) [only generates English type quotes](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/84). But you have two options:

1. You can use the `--no-tex-ligatures` option to turn off the [`--smart` typography](http://pandoc.org/README.html#reader-options) option which is turned on by default for LaTeX output. Then use the proper unicode characters (e.g. `„...”`) you desire and use a `--latex-engine` that supports unicode (`lualatex` or `xelatex`).
2. You could use `\usepackage[danish=quotes]{csquotes}` or similar in your [Pandoc LaTeX template](http://pandoc.org/README.html#templates). From the [README](http://pandoc.org/README.html#smart-punctuation):

   > If the `--smart` option is specified, pandoc will produce typographically correct output, converting straight quotes to curly quotes, `---` to em-dashes, `--` to en-dashes, and `...` to ellipses. Nonbreaking spaces are inserted after certain abbreviations, such as “Mr.”
   >
   > Note: if your LaTeX template calls for the [csquotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package, pandoc will detect this automatically and use `\enquote{...}` for quoted text.

Answer (score 1):

Even though [@mb21](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33953762/3753169) already provided an answer, I would like to add, that nowadays it's possible to simply include what you need in (for example) your [yaml metadata block](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block), so it is not necessary anymore to create your own template. Example:

```
---
title: foo
author: bar
# other stuff
header-includes:
    - \usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
---

# contents
```